# Get coordinates from google maps link

Tags: google-maps, share

I have a share google maps link like this: https://maps.app.goo.gl/rFtzbfFRr1aKTFJN6

Can I extract latitude a longitude coordinates from that, in console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, the process you are talking about is referred to as reverse geocoding.

This is possible using google API and you should be able to find everything you need to do this in there documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=de#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Ok, thanks. With that I can get the place_id of the url link and convert into coordinates. 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA
&key=YOUR_API_KEY'